# What is happening with this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working with the python3 `re` module to strip a string of anything not a digit or a `'.'`

My first try was this:

```
r = re.sub('[^0-9].', '', s)
```

And of course anytime I had a `'.'` in there it wouldn't work right. So I added a backslash in front of the `'.'` and it works perfectly.

My question is, while I understand why the first expression didn't work, I do not understand why it would match both the `'.'` character and the character immediately after it.

What I would have expected from reading the documentation is that given a string of `'15.45'` I would have ended up with a string like this: `'1545'`, since the `'.'` would match all characters except the 0-9 that I already excluded.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is happening here?

Comment: *anything not a digit or a '.'* - a dot is a non-digit. Are you just trying to remove all non-digits? `r'\D+'` will suffice.

Comment: Your pattern matches two characters: the first character is anything that is *not* a digit, the second character could be anything (including a digit). Thus, `.4` would match your pattern. That gets replaced by nothing, and you end up with `155`.

Comment: Watch out, strings like f"this dot . has nothing to do with this number 15,450" will produce results like .15450 with that regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're matching two characters with `[^0-9].`.

Match 1: Something that is not a digit (`[^0-9]`)
Match 2: Anything (`.`)

Put the period match (`.`) inside your "not these characters" set instead:

```
import re
s = "b15_.45a"
re.sub('[^.0-9]+', '', s)
# '15.45'
```

That will give you "a string of anything not a digit or a '.'".

Comment: I’m pretty sure you don’t have to escape `.` inside a character class …

Comment: Might be faster to use `re.sub('[^.0-9]+', '', s)`. With the `+`, it matches one or more characters, so `sub` will replace entire runs of unwanted characters, instead of replacing one character at a time.